# Program icon not appearing in window list when running

Tags: 16.04, .desktop, cinnamon

Running under the Cinnamon Desktop Environment on Ubuntu 16.04, I have a desktop file for my app in ~/Desktop/ that shows up just fine and launches my app.

However, when the app appears in the window list on the panel, its icon is just a generic "window" icon rather than the icon used on the desktop.

Other apps work just fine so I'm wondering if it is something to do with running the app with gksudo (the app is in the sudoers file).

Desktop file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Icon=my-app
Name=My App
Exec=gksudo /usr/bin/my-app
StartupWMClass=my-app
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking in the wrong place. The icon in the window list is taken from the app itself. In this case my gtk app simply required a new property adding to its `GtkApplicationWindow`:

```
<property name="icon">/usr/share/icons/my-app.png</property>
```

And all was well.